# MongoDB - How to sum 2 string values in array after their conversion to integer?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, sum, aggregation-framework

I've been breaking my head on this for a while now:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "12sdsd",
    "TotalStudent": [
      "10"
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "22fdf",
    "TotalStudent": [
      "20"
    ]
  }
]
```

I need to sum the two values after conversion from String to Integer.
This doesn't work:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "",
      TotalStudents: {
        $sum: {
          $toInt: "$TotalStudent.0"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

See the playground, what am I doing wrong?
https://mongoplayground.net/p/Evm3tJUGmKa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"$TotalStudent.0"` - This is not a valid syntax with aggregation queries. When working with array fields in aggregations, use [Aggregation Array Operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/operator/aggregation/#array-expression-operators). The operator to get an element of an array by its index is `$arrayElemAt`. So, the following `$group` stage will work fine:

```
{ $group: { 
    _id: "", 
    TotalStudents: { $sum: { $toInt: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$TotalStudent", 0 ] } } } 
} }
```